# How to deploy beta desktop software

Tags: deployment

I work for a small startup that is entering its first beta trial for a very small number of customers, and we need to be able to give them code updates.  The software product runs only on Windows 10.  We used Inno to create setup.exe that is about 55Mb in size. My first idea was just to make a Downloads page on our website, and post updates there. Our company website is hosted by Wix.com, and their support group says they limit the file size of downloads to 15Mb, and do not support downloading of exe files.

We don't want to use adfly, and most of what I'm finding seems to be overpowered for our needs.  What other options are there?

Answer (score 1):

You could have an amazon s3 bucket and provide a link from your website to the bucket

Comment: Thanks.  I'm looking into both amazon s3 and Google Cloud now.  I also found out that BitBucket (where our source code repository is stored) includes a 2GB Download section.  I was able to load a file there and then download it from our website.